# Chrome web driver. Manual mouse events are handled in new windows and javascript popups

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Steps:

1. Start chrome browser using web driver.
2. Open link in new window (using mouse).

Expected result:
The new window handle all mouse events(click, hover etc.). The new window can't be closed, moved by mouse. The page is not reacted to mouse.

Java script alerts have same problems.

UPD: reproduced on Windows 10, not reproduced on Windows 7

UPD2: I am interested in hybrid usage, when I try to use hardware mouse to manage windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow you, but it seems like the page not responding? is it reproducible manually?

If you want to simulate, mouse events, I recommend using actions chain, here is the reference of the api https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html

Comment: Actually no, I am interested in hybrid usage, when I try to use hardware mouse to manage windows.